I am Having Trouble with the turtle module in python while writing text
my main.py
new_food = Food()
cords = new_food.food()
score_food = Food()
score_food.write_score(0)
while is_on:
    my_screen.update()
    time.sleep(.01)
    is_on = snake.move()

    if snake.head.distance(cords) < 15:
        score_food.clear()
        score = new_food.increase_score(score)

        new_food = Food()
        cords = new_food.food()

my food.py
from turtle import Turtle
import random


class Food(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def food(self):
        self.shape('circle')
        self.shapesize(.5, .5)
        self.color('blue')
        x = random.randint(-270, 270)
        y = random.randint(-280, 280)
        while x % 10 != 0:
            x += 1
        while y % 10 != 0:
            y += 1
        self.teleport(x, y)
        return x, y

    def increase_score(self, score):
        score += 1
        self.clear()
        self.write_score(score)
        return score

    def write_score(self, score):
        self.clear()
        self.color('white')
        self.penup()  # Lift the pen to prevent drawing lines
        self.goto(0, 250)  # Move to the desired position
        self.hideturtle()
        self.write(f"Score is: {score}", align="center", font=("Arial", 24, "normal"))



The score on the top of the screen shows overlapping , but it works no problem for 1 but afterwords the score is getting over layered upon each other
I have tried to .clear() and .undo() it but it has no effect

Large chunks of your program haven't been provided so it's impossible for me to give you a detailed answer but in general, I would make the score writer its own turtle so that clearing it only affects what it's written and you never have to move it, or set its color, etc. after its initial setup.

Thank you for the suggestion. I got the answer and moved the whole scorecard to another class  which seemed to have the done the job
